# How to Format text in php

Tags: php, regex, text-formatting

I am generating text from pdf file with the help of [**pdftotext**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/converter-pdf-files-to-text-format-command/)
My issue is not with pdftotext but it is with formating the text accordingly

```
Salman              Madhuri             Mohnish             Renuka                Anupam
Khan                Dixit               Behl                Shahane               Kher
Prem                Nisha Chou...       Rajesh              Pooja Chou...         Prof. Siddh


Hum Aapke Hain Koun...! (1994) - Full cast and crew
www.imdb.com/title/tt0110076/fullcredits
Hum Aapke Hain Koun...! on IMDb: Movies, TV, Celebs, and more... ... IMDbPro.com
offers representation listings for over 120,000 individuals, including actors, ...
```

I need output to be as

```
Salman Khan Prem
Madhuri Dixit Nisha Chou...
Mohnish Behl Rajesh
Renuka Shahane Pooja Chou...
Anupam Kher Prof.

Hum Aapke Hain Koun...! (1994) - Full cast and crew
www.imdb.com/title/tt0110076/fullcredits
Hum Aapke Hain Koun...! on IMDb: Movies, TV, Celebs, and more... ... IMDbPro.com
offers representation listings for over 120,000 individuals, including actors, ...
```

Comment: What are the delimiters?

Comment: Show us some code that produces this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your delimiters are, but you could something like the following (kinda ugly, but it gets the job done):

```
$namesAndContent = explode("\r\n\r\n", $theString);
$nameRows = explode("\r\n", $namesAndContent[0]);
$names = array();
foreach ($nameRows as $row) {
    $items = preg_split('/\s{2,}/', $row);
    foreach ($items as $index => $namePart) {
        if (!array_key_exists($index, $names)) {
            $names[$index] = array();
        }
        $names[$index][] = $namePart;
    }

}

foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo implode(' ', $name) . "\r\n";
}
echo "\r\n";
echo $namesAndContent[1];
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Nr1Q4t

*The above would format the data (when the delimiters are correct), but I am wondering where the data is coming from (originaly and not the pdf), because I suspect there is a better way to solve your problem. Perhaps there is some API you can directly utilize*

Comment: It didnt worked out for other text if their is more \n\n in string...Can you plz suggest how to solve that....

Comment: What is the other text, and what *is* the delimiter.